# How to send Salesforce data to some Cloud storage site (Alternate to FTP)

Tags: apex, ftp

I know I cannot send data to FTP via apex code. But is there a way I could send Salesforce data and attachments to dropbox or any other such site via apex code.

Thanks

Comment: You should look into Heroku connect

Answer (score 1):

Any storage service that offers a HTTP-based API will work. There are many services that qualify - Microsoft OneDrive, Google Drive, AWS S3, Dropbox, ...

Comment: Thanks for the help. ok I am looking for a free of cost solution. What would I have to do to connect salesforce with Google drive, Dropbox, some sort of connector e.t.c? Would that be free? Do you have any sample links that I could follow to obtain this?

Answer (score 1):

One way could be sending Data using Heroku service. So essentially you send data over to your Heroku server and then using a NodeJS script you send the data over using FTP. It is fairly straight forward. Second solution is using a free app from appExchange. You can get one like this: https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016ZwDEAU

Comment: Thanks for the help. Would sending to Heroku free of cost? Also, if I go to appexchange tool FTP attachments, is it gonna let me send Salesforce data as well as attachments free of cost too?

Comment: Heroku will be free if you are under the usage limits. I haven't used the appExchange app myself but I don't see a reason why attachments shouldn't be allowed. Checking out the app will give you a good idea. Also, if this answer helped you, it would be really great if you could mark it as the correct answer.